# sql query returns error when using limit

Tags: php, sql, mysql

why does this query work? how am i supposed to write it?

```
select * from tbl_content order by year desc where visible = '1' limit 0,30;
```

Answer (score 3):

WHERE Clauses come before ORDER BY.

Rewrite as:

```
select * from tbl_content where visible = '1'  order by year desc limit 0,30;
```